# How to edit the API key on the `amplify graphQL Explora`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I want to edit auth on the explorer and enter my API key for local testing but the input field is readonly.

How do I change/set it?

## Amplify CLI Version

12.1.1

## GraphQL Explorer

[image]

## What I tried

1. Schema built successfully
2. I ran `amplify mock api`
3. Viewed the graphQL explorer on `http://127.0.0.1:20002`
4. Attempted to update auth

## What I expected

To be able to edit/set the api key for local mocking